# How to correctly make a counter work in java

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, ide

I'm a beginner student with java and this is part of an assignment I have to do for my online course using the programming language java in the NetBeans IDE.

We are required to create an application that asks the user to click on a total of twenty bananas without going over. If they do go past 20 bananas, they must start again. And the label should display the user's total banana count.

I've been trying to follow the steps, but I don't really understand what I'm doing. I have some code, but I'm not sure how to code it so it declares globally and where to go from there.
[Here's an image of the code I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyux8.png)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to include your code textually into this question and to narrow down the problem-space. We will not write your project, but will help with concrete issues that you may have.

Comment: Why in the world you post a link where we need to enter your Grand Erie email and password to access the information. This just doesn't make sense. And NO, don't post that information here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment a counter variable then you can do:

```
banana = banana + 1;  ( or banana ++; )     // Increment by 1
banana = banana + 2;  ( or banana += 2; )   // Increment by 2
banana = banana + 2;  ( or banana += 3; )   // increment by 3
etc.....
```

If you want to check if a counter variable has reached a specific threshold then you can do:

```
String msg = "";
if (banana == 20) {
    msg = "You have reached your expected banana count of 20.";
    banana = 0;
}
else if (banana > 20) {
    msg = "You have exceeded your banana count by " + 
          (banana - 20) + " bananas. Starting again from 0";
    banana = 0;
}
else {
    msg = "You have added " + banana + " bananas. Keep going.";
}
```